# Is there any cache for pytest running with parametrize?

Tags: python, pytest

case_id in the following code gets value from the last call.  How can I reset or disable the cache feature if there is some feature that caused this issue?

```
def setup_class(self):
    global case_id_list
    test_runner = TestRunner()
    case_id_list = test_runner.get_run_List()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('case_id', case_id_list)
def testcase(self, case_id, json_metadata):
    print("case_id in testcase: "+ case_id)
    print("case_id_list in testcase: " + str(case_id_list))
```

**running log for the first time, in this case, running correctly:**

collecting ... collected 4 items

../testcase_folder/test_runner.py::TestClass::testcase[210426343] get_run_List: testcase_run_list: [210426343, 210426628, 210426645, 210426712]
case_id in testcase: 210426343
case_id_list in testcase: [210426343, 210426628, 210426645, 210426712]

**running log for the second time, in this case, it seems like running with the values passed in the last call:**

collecting ... collected 4 items

../testcase_folder/test_runner.py::TestClass::testcase[210426343] get_run_List: testcase_run_list: ['210426645']
case_id in testcase: 210426343
case_id_list in testcase: ['210426645']

Comment: It is not clear how you invoke pytest. Can you share? I presume that the problem can be with the modification of the global variable ``case_id_list``. Why do you do it?

Comment: The parameters (e.g. `case_id_list`) are read at load time, not at run time, setting them up at this point is too late. If you want to populate the list dynamically, you have to do it in `pytest_generate_tests`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used `pytest_generate_tests` and problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

By following MrBean's solution, I solved the problem by using `pytest_generate_tests` to replace `@pytest.mark.parametrize`

More info about pytest_generate_tests could found at https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example